# Face culling - Hide all the faces that are not front-faces in a cube

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to discard all the faces in a cube that are not front-faced, and the command `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);` doesn't work for me. this is my cube coordinates

```java
 private float cubeCoords[] = {
                -0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,   // front top left 0
                -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,   // front bottom left 1
                0.25f, -0.25f, 0.25f,   // front bottom right 2
                0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,  // front top right 3
                -0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,   // back top left 4
                0.25f, 0.25f, -0.25f,   // back top right 5
                -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f,   // back bottom left 6
                0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f};
```

and the drawOrder is:

```java
    private short drawOrder[] = {
            0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,//front
            0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 3, //Top
            0, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, //left
            3, 2, 7, 3, 7 ,5, //right
            1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 6, //bottom
            4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5};
```

while the cube is rotating the i can see a face on the cube that in the background.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) then you've to respect the winding order. If face culling is enabled, then by defualt backfaces are culled, if the winding order of the faces is counter-clockwise. See [`glFrontFace`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFrontFace.xhtml) respectifely [`glCullFace`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCullFace.xhtml).

Sort the vertices from the front to the back, and in counter-clockwise order, starting at the top left:

```java
private float cubeCoords[] = {
    -0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f, // front top    left  0
    -0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f, // front bottom left  1
     0.25f, -0.25f,  0.25f, // front bottom right 2
     0.25f,  0.25f,  0.25f, // front top    right 3
    -0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f, // back  top    left  4
    -0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f, // back  bottom left  5
     0.25f, -0.25f, -0.25f, // back  top    right 6
     0.25f,  0.25f, -0.25f  // back  bottom right 7
};
```

The proper counter clockwise triangle faces are:

```java
private short drawOrder[] = {
    0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3, // front
    4, 0, 3,   4, 3, 7, // top
    5, 1, 0,   5, 0, 4, // left
    7, 3, 2,   7, 2 ,6, // right
    1, 5, 6,   1, 6, 2, // bottom
    7, 6, 5,   7, 5, 4  // back
};
```

Note, you've to define the faces in that way, that the winding order is counter-clockwise, when you look at it form the "outside" of the cube (mesh).